# Make heading center align

Tags: html, css, alignment

How to center `<h3>` in the following code?

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>title 1</h1>
    <h3>title 3</h3>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/4a12rLs2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add a class to `<div>` and style `<div>`.

Currently, you `<div>` like parent. Set `text-align: center`.

Example:

```css
h1{
  color: #666;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

 h3 {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
        <h1>title 1</h1>
        <h3>title 3</h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that thing do the job!

Answer (score 13):

Just apply this css property to the div i.e **text-align:center;**

like this

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>title 1</h1>
    <h3>title 3</h3>
</div>
```

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/egv269x0/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you read previous messages before answering by any chance? this has been said before. Thanks

Comment: I think this is more simplified way and easy to understand solution. Without any need to assign class and then writing separate css code.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this css to the h3:

```
h3 {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  //text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

The way you tried to do it doesn't work because when using `display: inline-block;` the element is not full-width anymore and `text-align: center;` centers the text according to the element's width.

Comment: This work too! Difference between this and the one provided by @varioc? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in a div and add style `text-align: center`. :)

Comment: Someone said the same few time ago. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center title 3 : 
It work without `display: inline-block;` in css

Comment: the idea is to keep the black background as it is now, not taking the whole window width. Many thanks