# How to make h1 tag center with its actual width

Tags: html, css

I need to make h1 tag center and also need to make a border around it.
To prevent taking up more width I give `display: inline-block`  but the tag does not respond to `text-align: center` then.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is the Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make heading center align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999528/make-heading-center-align)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following on parent tag instead of `h1` tag

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: This will still make the border, take up the whole width. Not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `display: table` on heading. This will make heading to have width depending on its content while it will remain a block level element as well. And you can center it using `margin: 0 auto` property.

```css
.heading {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading 1</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be your HTML.

```
<div class="heading">
 <h1>My Heading</h1>
</div>
```

this will go into CSS

```
.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading h1 {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: do you find it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow @gavgrif instructions.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
</div>  

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

span {
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute;` and `transform`

```css
.heading {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading 1</h1>
```

Comment: This won't position it relatively to its parent/container which can be of any size.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @j10i2  - .container{text-align:center;}, but another way to do it is to center content within the h1. The h1 is a block level element - so insert a span into it and place the text within that. Now applying the text-align: center will allow the centering of the span within the h1.

UPDATE - I just noticed that you want a border around the centered content - this is easy - apply the boder to the span that has been centered within the h1.

```css
h1 {
text-align:center;
}

h1 span {
 border: solid 1px #333;
 padding:5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Heading 1</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap you can use the class ***text-center***

here is the example what i can understand from your query

**HTML:**

```
<div class="head">
  <h1>Game Over</h1>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.head{width:100%;float:left;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}
 h1{border:1px solid red;text-align:center;position:relative;}
 h1:after{position:absolute;content:"";top:0;width:200px;height:38px;border:1p    x solid green;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, 0);}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cyndw8L/1/)