# I can't align my header even though I have used 'text-align: center'

Tags: html, text-align

Hey there I'm new to html.
My problem is that I can't get my h3 heading to align. The h3 heading is in my body which has css code that centers the body. It aligns to the left and yet it should align to the center. I have saved both the html and css file and refreshed my browser.
Here is the html code:

```
<body>
    
    
    <h1> 
        Blessed Be Blessings
    </h1>

<p class="width"> Hey there. What's up?</p>
<br>
<h3>Titanium Steel</h3>

<img src="file:C:/Users/Tam/Desktop/1.jpg">
  

</body>
```

Here is the css:

```
body{background-color: powderblue;}

p{color: white;}



body {text-align: center;}

h1 {border: solid 5px; background-color: white;}
h3{border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; padding: 40; width: 200px; background-color: purple;}
```

Comment: try margin: 0px auto; or display: inline-block; on h3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make heading center align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999528/make-heading-center-align)

Answer (score 1):

`h3` is a **block type tag**. When you use the `width`, it is aligned to its `200px` space but not to the body. So you have to use

```
h3 {
    margin:0px auto 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

display: inline-block;

```css
body{background-color: powderblue;}

p{color: white;}



body {text-align: center;}

h1 {border: solid 5px; background-color: white;}
h3{border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; padding: 40; width: 200px; background-color: purple;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<body>
    
    
    <h1> 
        Blessed Be Blessings
    </h1>

<p class="width"> Hey there. What's up?</p>
<br>
<h3>Titanium Steel</h3>
<br>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap h3 inside a div and make that div a flexbox.

Please see below example

```css
p {
  color: white;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  border: solid 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

h3 {
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  padding: 40;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}

.center-h3 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Blessed Be Blessings
</h1>

<p class="width"> Hey there. What's up?</p>
<br>
<div class='center-h3'>
  <h3>Titanium Steel</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  border: solid 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

h3 {
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  padding: 40;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>
    Blessed Be Blessings
  </h1>

  <p class="width"> Hey there. What's up?</p>
  <br>
  <h3>Titanium Steel</h3>

  <img src="file:C:/Users/Tam/Desktop/1.jpg">

</body>
```

Comment: That code seems to align everything to the center. I'm not seeing the isssue.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the margin-left property to  centre it.

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  border: solid 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
h3 {
  margin-left: 40%;/*This value can be adjusted */
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  /*padding: 40;*No padding unit provided so it will not make any changes*/
  width: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>
    Blessed Be Blessings
  </h1>

  <p class="width"> Hey there. What's up?</p>
  <br>
  <h3>Titanium Steel</h3>

  <img src="file:C:/Users/Tam/Desktop/1.jpg" alt="img">

</body>
```